# Passing PHP String as SQL Command and Preserving Line Breaks

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I am trying to **run a SQL stored procedure**, and am passing the execution command to the server **using PHP's PDO class**. Here's my script as it stands now:

```
$db = new PDO("dblib:dbname=databaseName;host=hostName", databaseUser, databasePassword);
$query = "
    USE [thisDatabase]
    GO
    DECLARE @return_value int
    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[thisSproc]
            @State = 'GA',
            @Type = 'Counseling',
            @PVCampusVueCode = NULL
    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
    GO";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Note that that query, when run directly on the database itself, returns results correctly without error.

However, when I run it using my PHP script and I parse the result, I get a syntax error near the word 'GO' (SQL error 102). This turns out to be because the command is being *passed to the SQL server as a single line, without line breaks*. So, it ends up looking like this:

```
USE [thisDatabase] GO DECLARE @return_value int EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[thisSproc] @State = 'GA', @Type = 'Counseling', @PVCampusVueCode = NULL SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value GO
```

This is a problem, because obviously the 'GO' command has to be on it's own line.

I have looked around for a fix to this, and can't find one. How do I either preserve the line breaks so the query executes correctly, or solve the problem some other way?

Comment: Just remove the `GO`s. Use `[thisDatabase].[dbo].[thisSproc]` when calling the procedure. You could separate the rest with semi-colons.

Comment: GO is NOT a sql statement. It is the default batch terminator in SSMS. Also when wanting to return a value from a procedure you should use an OUTPUT parameter. The return value is designed to return a status code indicating the status of the execution of the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run your queries as separate `query()` calls.